# Unable to update the quota file in cPanel

Tags: cpanel, whm

I added an addon domain to my account in cPanel and go this error message:

> "The addon domain has been created"

but it also said

```
"Error detected with pure-quotacheck for addondomainname [/home/username/public_html/addondomainname.com]: Unable to update the quota file(.ftpquota): [Permission denied]"
```

After all this I went inside the file manager to add a simple empty folder inside the addon domain folder and I get

> "Could not create folder ...., permission denied".

This is a dedicated server and I have access to cPanel and WHM but I'm not that experienced so I need your help. Can anybody help me with some advice on how to fix this problem so that I can create my website inside that addon domain folder? Right now I can't do anything inside it?  Thanks. I tried a few things but didn't succeed and I'm getting same messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ownership of the domain.com folder inside the public_html directory. It should point to the ftp user name.